# Use GAE remote api with local (dev) installation

Tags: api, google-app-engine

Has anyone find to use the GAE remote api but instead of connecting to AppEngine to connect to localhost?
For dev purposes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [development console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#The_Development_Console)? To access it, go to this URL: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin.

If you really want to use the remote API, have a look at [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html). I believe you can use the dev_server by passing the local host url to the interactive console script.

Comment: that s what i did eventually the problem was the i had added the remote_api url after the * handler so i could never reach the remote_api end point

Comment: @PanosJee I am having the same issue, will you post some code of how you connected to the local datastore?

Comment: @PanosJee its ok, ive just got it. if interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447489/how-to-upload-data-to-local-datastore/12450546#12450546

Answer (score 5):

i was able to get this working by adding the following to the app.yaml file

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

and then from the command line you can access the db, users, urlfetch or memcache modules

```
remote_api_shell.py -s localhost:8080
```

This will prompt you for the email and password but this is not important right now. the remote_api_shell.py is on my path from the google app engine directory

Comment: I had to use -s localhost:49500. Even when you start the server it clearly outputs this line: INFO     2013-07-30 07:55:45,537 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49500

Answer (score 1):

For Java see this document which explains both local and remote access
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#Configuring_Remote_API_on_the_Client

Answer (score 0):

If there are some like me who prefer to execute from a python script rather than a shell:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth('localhost:8081', '/_ah/remote_api', secure=False)
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Development'
os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost:8080'

... do stuff ...
```

I run the dev server with the option "--api_port 8081" otherwise just look at the port used in the dev server logs ("Starting API server at ...").

The environ tweaks are to be able to use cloudstorage api against the dev server too.