# How to upload data to local datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I can update the live datastore using the remote API but is there something similar for the local datastore ? My data is in CSV format.

When I try to connect locally using below code

```
String username = "test";
String password = "test";
    RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8888).credentials(username, password);
RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
installer.install(options);
```

I get an exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: http

The exception is thrown at line :

> installer.install(options);

The local server is running, am I connecting correctly ? Do I need to start the local remote_api server separately ?

Comment: You can use the remote_api to connect to the local dev server.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman thanks, please see question edit

Comment: When I added this comment you hadn't mentioned java is being used.  With python any userid/password will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work through alot of searching. The dev url/password is XXXX/XXXX

Taken from here : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/1cQWn0UEoMc

I havent been able to find this specified anywhere in the google app engine documentation.

Comment: These credentials don't seem to work anymore. When I try to use them, I get a com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.LoginException that says `Login failed. Reason: Bad Authentication.`